# Coin Flip HTML / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created coin flip in which we have two sides to  choose one is Global the other is Fortune. I used `<form>` and `<select>`, inside select I've added three `<option>`

```
<option value="">Select Your Side</option>
<option value="Global">Global</option>
<option value="Fortune">Forutne</option>
```

but after I choose e.g. Global and press button it flips then if I change it back to option "Select Your Side" it still flips... It shouldn't flip on it. Sorry for my bad English :/

Javascript / Jquery code:

```js
// JavaScript Document
// Resetting HTML after Result
var result,userchoice;
function resetAll(){
    var resetHTML = '<div class="tail"><img src="coin_F.png" /></div><div class="head"><img src="coin_G.png" /></div>';
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.coinBox').fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).html(resetHTML)
        }).fadeIn('slow',function(){
            $('#btnFlip').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    },2500);
}
// Checking User Input
$(document).on('change','#userChoice', function(){
    userchoice = $(this).val();
    if(userchoice == "") {
        $(this).parent('p').prepend("<span class='text text-danger'>Please select a coin side to play the game</span>")
        $('#btnFlip').attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        /**/
        $('#btnFlip').removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).siblings('span').empty();
    }
    return userchoice;
});
// Final result declaration
function finalResult(result,userchoice){
    var resFormat = '<h3>';
    resFormat += '<span class="text text-primary">You choose : <u>'+userchoice+'</u></span> |';
    resFormat += '<span class="text text-danger"> Result : <u>'+result+'</u></span>';
    resFormat += '</h3>';
    var winr = '<h2 class="text text-success" style="color: #49DF3E;">You Won!!</h2>';
    var losr = '<h2 class="text text-danger" style="color: #c34f4f;">You Lost...</h2>';
    if(result == userchoice){
        $('.coinBox').append(resFormat+winr)
    } else{
        $('.coinBox').append(resFormat+losr)
    }
}
// Button Click Actions
$(document).on('click','#btnFlip',function() {
    var flipr = $('.coinBox>div').addClass('flip');
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
        flipr.removeClass('flip');
        //result time
        if(number) {
            result = 'Global';
        //alert('Head = '+number);
            $('.coinBox').html('<img src="coin_G.png" /><h3 class="text-primary">Global</h3>');
            finalResult(result,userchoice);
            resetAll();
        } else {
            result = 'Fortune';
        //alert('Tail = '+number);
            $('.coinBox').html('<img src="coin_F.png" /><h3 class="text-primary">Fortune</h3>');
            finalResult(result,userchoice);
            resetAll();
        }
    },2000);
    return false;
});
```

```css
#wrapper 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.btn
{
    width: 12%;
    background-color: #c34f4f;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.btn:hover
{
    background-color: #A64242;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #A64242;
}

.container
{
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1
{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.head
{
    margin-top: -205px;
}

.flip img{animation: flipIt 0.5s linear infinite;}
.head img
{
    animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

@keyframes flipIt
{
    0%{width: 0px;
        height: 200px;}
    25%{width: 200px;
        height: 200px;}
    50%{width: 0px;
        height: 200px;}
    100%{width: 0px;
        height: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Coin Flip | <span>Global or Fortune</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!--blank-->
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <!--coin-->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="coinBox">
                        <div class="tail">
                            <img src="coin_F.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="head">
                            <img src="coin_G.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--user form elements-->
                <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
                    <form>
                        <p>
                        <select class="form-control" id="userChoice">
                            <option value="">Select Your Side</option>
                            <option value="Global">Global</option>
                            <option value="Fortune">Forutne</option>
                        </select>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="btnFlip" disabled>Flip It</button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your `resetAll` function, you should reset the `userchoice = "";` variable too.

Comment: "Forutne" ?  -- ;)

Comment: Opss :) I need to change that thanks for helping me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a safety check on button click as well. That way, it will always check before the click is triggered.

```
$(document).on('click','#btnFlip',function() {
    if($('#userChoice').val() == "") return;
    var flipr = $('.coinBox>div').addClass('flip');
```

See the fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/45t3th0n/

Comment: Ty very much I've tried to find the solution for 2 hours and I only needed to write here and get good answer in 5 minutes :D basically I wasted 2 hours of my life... Really love this site

Comment: @Apocalypse no you didn't waste those hours, trying to find what is wrong with a code is a needed thing to do, it is what makes coding fun, its a skill its good to get better at, its ok if you didn't find what was wrong this time, but you will next time (as long as you try), good luck next time :v

Comment: @ajax333221 Good one mate

Comment: @Apocalypse may be accepting this as answer will help